# Calling HANA procedure in python

Tags: python, hana

I have a procedure which is in HANA, i am using python as my coding platform. I want to know how can I call HANA procedure in Python

CALL ""*SYS*"".""prd.abc.xyz::file_generation"" ("'"abc-121-xyz"'","'"5/15/2019"'","'"12"'","'"1000"'");

I made a call to procedure above any connecting to the HANA but it throws me an error.

CALL ""*SYS*"".""prd.abc.xyz::file_generation"" ("'"abc-121-xyz"'","'"5/15/2019"'","'"12"'","'"1000"'");

Answer (score 0):

The HANA [documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/1efad1691c1f496b8b580064a6536c2d/Cloud/en-US/f3b8fabf34324302b123297cdbe710f0.html) is quite good at this topic.

It's clearly stated that the [PEP 249 -- Python Database API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249) is the way to go here.

Given that your question does not contain any Python code and does also not specify what error you receive, I cannot know what is wrong with it.

Maybe it's easiest for you to look at an example for calling HANA procedures in Python, e.g. [this one](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/26/sap-hana-2.0-sps02-new-feature-updated-python-driver/).